# Запятая перед "как" внутри деепричастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

*Пнула, проследив(,) как шишка улетела.*

Нужна ли запятая?
Думаю, что нет, по аналогии со "смотря":

> Смотря, как он на охоте скакал всегда первый, не разбирая дороги,
> соседи говорили согласно, что из него никогда не выйдет путного
> столоначальника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Пнула, **проследив, как** шишка улетела.*

Запятая ставится (и как раз на том же основании, что и в примере со "смотря").
Если бы на месте деепричастия стоял глагол, мне кажется, мы бы не сомневались в пунктуации: *Проследила, как шишка улетела* – сложное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным.
Деепричастие по сути выполняет ту же основную функцию глагола.

*― спросила Марина, внимательно **проследив, как** он жует.* [Нина Садур. Сад (1994)]

*― спросил он, **проследив, как** ему наливали чай.* [Юрий Казаков. Ночлег (1963)]

***Проследив, как** он, царапая пером, размашисто расписывался, Кривицкий вздохнул.* [Даниил Гранин. Искатели (1954)]